# Javascript count up to an amount

Tags: javascript

I have a question, the count up works but how to add a class before each number so I can style it as a flipping box? I use countup.js https://inorganik.github.io/countUp.js/

HTML:

```
<h1 id="myTargetElement">2500000</h1>
```

Javascript:

```
const options = {
  decimalPlaces: 5,
  separator: '',
  decimal: '',
};

let demo = new CountUp('myTargetElement', 25, options);
if (!demo.error) {
  demo.start();
} else {
  console.error(demo.error);
}
```

This is what i want: https://pasteboard.co/IzMSBwy.jpg

Answer (score 0):

From the js file:

```js
...
var CountUp = function(target, startVal, endVal, decimals, duration, options) {
...
```

```js
const options = {
  decimal: ".",
  decimalPlaces: "5",
  //duration: 2,
  prefix: "",
  separator: ",",
  //startVal: "0",
  suffix: "",
  useEasing: true,
  useGrouping: true,
};

let demo = new CountUp('myTargetElement', 0, 250000, 0, 3, options);
//let demo = new CountUp('myTargetElement',250000,options);
if (!demo.error) {  
  demo.start(function() {
    console.log('finished')
  });
} else {  
  console.error(demo.error);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/countup@1.8.2/countUp.js"></script>
<h1 id="myTargetElement">0</h1>
```

Comment: Thanks, but i want that each number get a class, so that i can make a flipboard